# p:treeTable with ui:repeat in header

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using `ui:repeat` regularly in `p:dataTable` in a `<p:columnGroup type="header">`, mostly to set the *colspan* attribute which works fine. Examples below are simplified to concentrate on the issue.

```
<p:dataTable var="i" value="#{bean.data}">
  <f:facet name="header">Works fine</f:facet>
  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
      <ui:repeat var="c" value="#{bean.columns}">
        <p:column colspan="1" headerText="#{c.name}" />
      </ui:repeat>
    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>
  <p:column><h:outputText value="#{i.value}"/></p:column>                   
</p:dataTable>
```

Now let's come to `p:treeTable` and issue. A example with `p:columnGroup` is also working fine:

```
<p:treeTable var="i" value="#{reportPlanningMtefBean.tree}">
  <f:facet name="header">columnGroup fine in tree</f:facet>
  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
      <p:column colspan="1" headerText="a" />
      <p:column colspan="1" headerText="b" />
    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>
  <p:column><h:outputText value="#{i.value1}"/></p:column>
  <p:column><h:outputText value="#{i.value2}"/></p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

But I have no success with a `ui:repeat` in `p:treeTable`. The headers are simply not shown!

```
<p:treeTable var="i" value="#{reportPlanningMtefBean.tree}">
  <f:facet name="header">columnGroup fine in tree</f:facet>
  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
      <ui:repeat var="c" value="#{bean.columns}">
        <p:column colspan="1" headerText="#{c.name}"/>
      </ui:repeat>
    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>
  <p:column><h:outputText value="#{i.value1}"/></p:column>
  <p:column><h:outputText value="#{i.value2}"/></p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

Above examples are tested with PrimeFaces 5.2 (changed this to 6.0, too) and Mojarra 2.1.28-jbossorg-5.

Comment: Tried without the row and columgroup?

Comment: I need the `columnGroup` and `row` because a header with two rows is required.

Comment: TRY... to narrow down the problem